# $V$ is a simple $\text{End}_kV$-module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ and $A = \text{End}_k V$. How do I see that $V$ is a simple $A$-module?

Comment: You first show that $V$ is a (left) $A$-module and then show it has no non-zero proper submodules. Have you tried?